# Want to insert multiple rows with on php query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to get the value of a `<textarea>` field from multiple rows with variable name as `name="sts<?php $i ?>"` which should change according to the row like `sts0`, `sts1`, `sts2`, `sts3`, ... where `$i` is a variable changing with for loop.

Now I want the value of different rows assigned to their respective variable.

Here I am using  `method="post"`

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($list);
    $mobile[$i]=$row[1];
    $insan[$i]=$row[4];
    echo "<tr>
          <td>".($i+1)."</td><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td><td>".$row[4]."</td><td>".$row[5]."</td><td>".$row[6]."</td><td>".$row[7]."</td><td>".$row[8]."</td><td>".$row[9]."</td><td>" ?>
          <textarea cols="20" rows="3" name="sts<?php $i ?>" >Pending</textarea></td></tr>
          <?php " ";
}
```

After that I want to print this as in the code below. It prints the value of `$mobile` and `$insan` correctly but gives an error for `$_POST['sts'.$i.'']`:

![screenshot][1]

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
    echo "".$mobile[$i]." ".$insan[$i]." ".$_POST['sts'.$i.'']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: What error does it give for your $_POST? Also, have you tried setting up the $_POST index and using a single variable rather than an expression in the index? For example, on the line before echo, try $postIndex = 'sts'.$i; then in the echo line do $_POST[$postIndex]

Answer (score 0):

You have missed 'echo' In field name for textarea